# how to get a asp.net page event on user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have asp.net page which loads the user controls at run time I want to capture the save/cancel event of page on the user control.

User control will be load at run time so, for further development I don't want to change my code on page level.

Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it, with the help of observer pattern but with some more modification because my challenge is Page don't know which user control will be load on run-time in its place holder.

I create change-manager which holds the Observers references with their intended types(submit,cancel,viewonly)

Page holds the reference of change-manager and call the notify of change manager with (eventtype(enum),response(this.response object)) then change manager calls the update method In this method call Observers, kept in the dictionary of change-manager.

Iterate the dictionary and call their updates according to their interested event types.

Now I am free to remember the user-control reference of any type of casting.

Answer (score 0):

see below example of get user control from page you need to use public modifier

```
///user control code see event is public 

public void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ///do you stuff
}
/// page code
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  uc1.btn1_Click(sender,e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,but in this case I have to know who is uc1, in my case ABC.aspx can load any user control(uc1,uc2,ucn) on runtime and the user control should register himself for the page event no the page will explicitly trigger the user control event. hope you got my issue